# 1 extra table cell when a row is dropped with jQueryUI sortable (but Chrome only)

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, google-chrome

I have an application that uses jQuery, jQuery UI, and Backbone.js. A bug has recently developed where a row in the table when it is dropped (jQUery Sortable) a different row will sometimes shift over a row as if there was an extra cell, but upon inspection there is not. I have just noted that this only happens in Chrome, Chromium, and ChromeFrame.

Here is a screenshot of the problem area: http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/6870/screenshotkz.png

Here is a screenshot of the HTML in Chrome's inspection interface: http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/6985/screenshot1wdo.png
I have also copied the HTML below:

```
<tr id="17052151" class="wo">
<td>17052151</td>
<td>XXXXXXXXXXX</td>
<td>XXXXXXXXXXXXX</td>
<td>Parts Here</td>
<td>RR</td>
<td>10/28/11</td>
<td>10/28/11</td>
<td>10</td>
<td><input type="text" class="woComment" value=""></td>
<td class="removeWO">X</td>
</tr>
<tr id="10097756" class="wo">
<td>10097756</td>
<td>XXXXXXXXXXXX</td>
<td>XXXXX</td>
<td>Parts Here</td>
<td>NIS</td>
<td>10/04/11</td>
<td>10/28/11</td>
<td>10</td>
<td><input type="text" class="woComment" value=""></td>
<td class="removeWO">X</td>
</tr>
<tr id="10095965" class="wo">
<td>10095965</td>
<td>XXXXXXXX</td>
<td>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</td>
<td>Parts Here</td>
<td>NIS</td>
<td>09/16/11</td>
<td>10/10/11</td>
<td></td>
<td><input type="text" class="woComment" value=""></td>
<td class="removeWO">X</td>
</tr>
```

Since this problem does not occur in Firefox or IE8 I am thinking it might be a Chrome bug, but I wanted to see if anyone else had experienced this issue  before.

**EDIT**
I have found that calling the `.render()` function for my view element that the issue occurs in fixes this issue.

Comment: This is a chrome bug, but i haven't found a way to fix it. the most common suggestion is to do something that causes a redraw of the page.

Comment: You have to include the CSS before you're getting more help. Here's the basic fiddle, add the relevant CSS (and JS/HTML, if applicable): http://jsfiddle.net/cZ4n4/

Comment: @RobW http://jsfiddle.net/cZ4n4/2/ The same thing happens when you are sorting the rows instead of the columns, only, vertically

Comment: @RobW http://jsfiddle.net/cZ4n4/5/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am totally missing your point, but could you clarify: You do want the whole row to be sortable, meaning row 1, row 2 and row 3 are interchangeable by dragging?

If that was the case, you would actually make the tbody a sortable, not the tr; applying the sortable to the tr is what causes weird behaviour here, as jqueryui tries to make the contents of the tr sortable, which goes awefully bad. To sort the rows, make the tbody a sortable, so it tries sorting the table rows.

http://jsfiddle.net/cZ4n4/10/